# Problema en los grid

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola tengo un problema en los `grid` y es que tengo insertada una imagen en un `div` y aveces si que se me amolda al `height:auto` y aveces me supera el tamaño de este cosa que no entiendo la imagen que introduzco es de 1600x1600 pero eso no debería importar ya que se tendría que adaptar solo.Lo ideal seria que pasara lo de la 2 cuadricula pero no sé por que motivo me aparece así.

```css
.grid {
  margin-top: 2%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30%, 30%);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.container3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container3 div {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.container3 h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  border-bottom: solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.container3 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.titulo4 {
  border-color: cadetblue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Nanum Pen Script', cursive;
  color: #666;
  margin-top: -14%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  background-color: azure;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="imagen">
        <img class="tomakepu" src="cirera.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Prèssec Gabacho</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hey, cual es precisamente el problema que estas teniendo? Seria bueno que compartieras una captura de lo que vez y como quieres que se vea; si es posible tabien seria bueno que incluyeras el codigo de manera que se pueda ejecutar

Comment: El problema es que no tengo las fotos colgadas en interet. Pero como puedes ver hay fotos que me aparecen salidendose del div y eso que lo tengo en auto el height.

Comment: Según lo que veo no tienes creada la clase "tomakepu" en tu archivo css la misma es la que modifica los atributos de la imagen, únicamente tienes la clase container3 que usa todo el ancho disponible, lo que modificaría el grid para el ancho que tenga la imagen.

Comment: puedes utilizar `https://via.placeholder.com/1600` para generar una imagen de muestra cuando necesites mostrar un ejemplo... Ahora, rrecuerda que la imagen se encoge a lo ancho y mantiene su aspecto en lo alto, si la imagen es demasiado alta es normal que se "salga" del contenedor porque no tiene el mismo aspecto; puedes añadir un `overflow-y: hidden` al `grid-item` para que todo el contenido en exceso de la caja se oculte; esa seria la solucion mas sencilla

Comment: Comprendo, es una buena opción gracias. Una pena no poder darte como respuesta correcta al ser comentario...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion mas sencilla seria ocultar el contenido en exeso con `overflow: hidden` en el `grid-item`, siendo el contenedor principal; por la forma en que estas construyendo estos bloques, recuerda que tienes un espacio determinado.

Al agregar `width: 100%; height: auto;` a la imagen le ayudas a que siempre mantenga su forma, sin embargo, recuerda que dependiendo de sus dimensiones encajara o no encajara bien en el espacio que tienes determinado; no quiere decir que se va a ajustar a todos los espacios que puedan existir; si ese fuera tu proposito, la imagen si o si tendria que ser distorsionada para que encaje.

```css
.grid {
  margin-top: 2%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30%, 30%);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 12px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container3 div {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.container3 h2 {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
  border-bottom: solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.container3 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.titulo4 {
  border-color: cadetblue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Nanum Pen Script', cursive;
  color: #666;
  margin-top: -14%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  background-color: azure;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="imagen">
        <img class="tomakepu" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1600" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Prèssec Gabacho</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```